# Get values that occur n consecutive times

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with the following structure:

| UserId | Date | Store |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 01/01/2020 | Red |
| 12 | 01/01/2020 | Orange |
| 12 | 01/01/2020 | Red |
| 12 | 13/01/2020 | Red |
| 12 | 15/02/2020 | Blue |
| 12 | 20/02/2020 | Blue |
| 12 | 20/02/2020 | Blue |
| 13 | 01/01/2020 | Orange |
| 13 | 25/01/2020 | Orange |

So what I want is to select the last Store in which Users had 3 (or more) consecutive purchases.
If there were less than 3 consecutive purchases - last store should be chosen.

For example, the result for the table above will look like this:

| UserId | Store |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | Blue |
| 13 | Orange |

How can I do this with Pandas in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

```
m1 = df['Store'] != df['Store'].shift()

m2 = df.groupby(['UserId', m1.cumsum()])['Store'].transform('count').ge(3)
m3 = m2.groupby(df['UserId']).transform('any')

out = df[m2 | ~m3].drop_duplicates('UserId', keep='last')
```

### Explanation

- Compare the values in `Store` with the previous value in order to create a boolean mask `m1`

```
>>> m1

# 0      True
# 1      True
# 2      True
# 3     False
# 4      True
# 5     False
# 6     False
# 7      True
# 8     False
# 9      True
# 10     True
# Name: Store, dtype: bool
```

- Calculate **cumulative sum** on the mask to identify the blocks of rows where the values in store column remains same, then group the dataframe on `UserId` along with these blocks and `transform` using `count` to calculate the number of consecutive visits by the user for each store. Now compare the counts of consecutive visits with `3` to create a boolean mask `m2`

```
>>> m2

# 0     False
# 1     False
# 2     False
# 3     False
# 4      True
# 5      True
# 6      True
# 7     False
# 8     False
# 9     False
# 10    False
# Name: Store, dtype: bool
```

- Group the mask created in the previous step on `UserId` and `transform` using `any` to determine whether the user has visited any one of the store at least three times consecutive in a row

```
>>> m3

# 0      True
# 1      True
# 2      True
# 3      True
# 4      True
# 5      True
# 6      True
# 7     False
# 8     False
# 9     False
# 10    False
# Name: Store, dtype: bool
```

- Take the logical or of `m2` and not `m3` to filter the rows, then drop the duplicate values keeping the last row per `UserId`

```
>>> out

#    UserId        Date   Store
# 6      12  20/02/2020    Blue
# 8      13  25/01/2020  Orange
```